# On forcing download: File Download dialog opens twice in IE6 SP1

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6, download

My ASP.Net page is supposed to create a document and force its download (open a "File Download" dialog). It works fine on most browsers but for some reason, on IE6 SP1 (windows 2000) the "File Download" dialog opens twice. 
Any ideas why?

My very simple code (C#):

```
protected void bnCreateDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string documentText = GetDocumentText();


    Response.Clear();
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

    string filename = "MyDoc.doc";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);

    Response.Write(documentText);
    Response.End();
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any browser addin installed as part of the browser (IE6 SP1), that can catch such a link to give you a "save.." dialog?

Comment: Nice idea, but no. I tried it on a freshly installed system and it still happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine but there are a couple of odd things about it that I thought I'd point out.

If you're just fetching a file from the filesystem into that string, why not use [`Response.WriteFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) directly?

Also, `Response.End()` automatically calls `Flush()` if buffering is on, so you shouldn't be calling `Flush()` at the end like that - at best, it should be before the call to End.  `End()` also raises a `ThreadAbortedException`, so if you can avoid calling it altogether, that would be ideal.  If you can use [`HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx), that's a better approach.

There are some very tricky and obscure bugs to deal with when shutting down the Response object.  If after dealing with the Flush and End calls it's still happening, I would examine what's going on with Fiddler, and perhaps try moving this code into an .ashx handler to get it out of the page lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The reason I'm not using WriteFile is because I'm not using a file from the filesystem, but rather creating the document on the fly.
That's very useful information about Response.End(). I will try using CompleteRequest and see how that works.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, I tryed HttpApplication.CompleteRequest(), but it still acts the same.
Fiddler was no help either, since nothing seems to be happening between the first and the second Download File dialogs...